# How can i get objectId in parse cloud code?

Tags: cloud, parse-platform

i haven succeeded in querying a class and retrieving objects.
however, i couldn't extract the `objectId` field from the data always gives me `"undefined"`.
but i can extract the `createdAt` and other fields.

how can i read the `objectId` field?

Regards

Comment: Show us what you've tried, specifically the code that tries (and fails) to read this. Be aware that the property is case-sensitive, so `objectId` and `objectID` are not the same. Also note that the `id` property might be what you want.

Comment: Yvan, how did you querying a class and retrieving objects?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Parse Objects in JavaScript (which also applies to Cloud Code) have these three properties, as per the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-retrieving):

```
var objectId = gameScore.id;
var updatedAt = gameScore.updatedAt;
var createdAt = gameScore.createdAt;
```